# String validation with regex not work

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need validate game levels in text file in follow format:

```
 #####
#   ####
#      #
### **# #
#  #* *@#
#   * ###
#  ##  #
##     #
#.$#  #
#  ####
 ####
```

Here  is my Java code:

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s#.$*@+]");
static BufferedReader br;
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
while ( (x = br.readLine()) != null ) {
  System.out.println(x.toLowerCase());
  System.out.println(isLineValid(x));
```

}
   ...
   }

```
private static boolean isLineValid(String line) {
    if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Whats wrong with my regex? Because I allways get false. Thanks

Comment: As you return false in any case in *isLineValid()* than you have all cases false.

Comment: Why you just return *pattern.matcher(line).matches()* ?

Comment: But question is why ... I always have only this seven chars ...

Comment: There are multiple issues here: 1) `matches()` requres a full string match thus the pattern must be `Pattern.compile("[\\s#.$*@+]*")`, 2) `isLineValid` always returns *false*, must be turned into `if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
      return true;
   }`

Comment: You only return false in both cases

Comment: @NikolasAlg the first problem, is you always return false on your function, so you don't know where the code pass until you debug it. This practice lead to further issues and make debugging complicated. Then Wiktor answer the issue here: your regexp maches just 1 char of the line, and the method you're calling it require the full string matches to return true. But if you don't fix the previous issue, you still see *false* print out

Comment: Since there are multiple issues here, I think OP deserves an answer. Just setting true and false in the `isLineValid` method would not be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only match a single character with your pattern, you need to match zero/one or more with `*` or `+` quantifiers. Mind that the `Matcher#matches()` method requires a full string match.

So, you need

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s#.$*@+]*")
```

Note that you do not need to overescape certain chars inside a character class.

Besides, the `isLineValid` always returns *false*, you need to make sure one branch that tests if the line matches your pattern will return *true*.

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/Ep5fas) printing "Valid":

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s#.$*@+]*"); // < -- Fixed pattern

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String s = " #####\n#   ####\n#      #\n### **# #\n#  #* *@#\n#   * ###\n#  ##  #\n##     #\n#.$#  #\n#  ####\n ####";
        if (isLineValid(s)) {
            System.out.println("Valid"); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Valid"); 
        }
    }

    private static boolean isLineValid(String line) {
       if (pattern.matcher(line).matches()) {
          return true;                            // <-- Returning TRUE here
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```